# Python pygame rect.colliderect only resets position temporarily

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a pygame where you fly a (SpaceX) rocket and then have it land on a sea-barge (OfCourseIStillLoveYou).

I also have an International Space Station (ISS) flying in orbit which if the rocket hits you lose a life. I used colliderect to do this.

The problem comes that after the collision the rocket is meant to return to its original starting position on the landing pad and the ISS station return to its original starting position in orbit. But after a brief pause - they return to image of their collision.

The game is run here...

```
import sys
import pygame
from rocket_settings import RocketSettings
from rocket_game_stats import GameStats
from rocket import Rocket
from iss import ISS
from rocket_barge import Barge
import rocket_game_functions as rgf
from rocket_plume import RocketPlume

def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = RocketSettings()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, 
        ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Rocket Launch!!!')
    background_image = pygame.image.load('images/moonsky.jpg')

    # Creat an instance to store game statistics
    stats=GameStats(ai_settings)

    # Make a rocket (with plume), ISS and barge
    barge = Barge(ai_settings, screen)  
    rocket = Rocket(ai_settings, screen)
    iss = ISS(ai_settings, screen)
    rocketplume = RocketPlume(ai_settings, screen, rocket)


    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        rgf.check_events(rocket)
        if stats.game_active:
            rocket.updategravity()
            rocket.update()
            rgf.update_iss(ai_settings, stats, screen, rocket, iss)
            rgf.update_barge(ai_settings, barge)
            rocketplume.update(rocket)
        rgf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, rocket, rocketplume, iss,
            barge)
        screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])

run_game()
```

I cannot include all the code because there is too much but this is the relevant code re: creating an instance of the ISS, what to do if the iss is hit, and updating ISS (if there is a collision)

```
def create_iss(ai_settings, screen, iss):
    iss = ISS(ai_settings, screen)
    iss.rect.centerx = 800
    iss.rect.top = iss.screen_rect.top

def iss_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, rocket, iss):
    if stats.rockets_left >0:
        # Decrement rockets_left
        stats.rockets_left -= 1

        # Create new iss and place ship
        rocket.rocket_at_launchpad()
        create_iss(ai_settings, screen, iss)

        # Pause
        sleep(0.5)
    else: 
        stats.game_active = False

def update_iss(ai_settings, stats, screen, rocket, iss):
    """Check if iss is at an edge, and then update ISS position"""
    check_iss_edges(ai_settings, iss)
    iss.update()

    # Look for alien-rocket collisions.
    if rocket.rect.colliderect(iss.rect):
        iss_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, rocket, iss)
```

This is the rocket_at_launchpad code.... referenced above...

```
def rocket_at_launchpad(self):
        # Start each new rocket at the launchpad screen
        self.rect.centerx = 120
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
```

And this is the rocket_game_stats code...

```
class GameStats():
    """Track statistics for Spacex landing"""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings):
        """Initialize statistics."""
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.reset_stats()
        # Start SpaceX game in an active state.
        self.game_active = True

    def reset_stats(self):
        """Initialize statistics that can change during the game."""
        self.rockets_left = self.ai_settings.rocket_limit
```

Finally these are some screenshots from what happens in the game. 
Initially the game loads with the ISS (and the barge) moving back and forth and the rocket stationary at the launchpad
[start of game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYJiw.jpg)

Then flying the rocket up the screen to hit the ISS the rocket then resets to the launchpad temporarily as expected. Before (after a pause) returning to the place where it collided with the ISS and is stuck there. 
[rocket & iss stuck after collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyqkE.jpg)

This is my first ever time posting on stackoverflow so if I've made a rookie ever in how I post, (friendly) feedback is most welcome. I've only been coding in python for about 3 weeks so your help is very much appreciated. I've stared at the code for hours now and I can't figure out what's gone wrong!!

Comment: I've figured out what the problem is but I still don't know how to solve it. I had 'stats.rocket_left' print to the command window and I found that rather than decrementing by one and then resetting the game, the game would freeze with the collision on the screen and the stats.rocket_left would quickly (in maybe a second) decrement down from 4 (initial number of lives) to zero.Having done so the game would freeze (because I hadn't coded what it should do when the player's lives run out)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell as you haven't included all the relevant code, but my guess is that you aren't updating the rocket image rect after the collision.  You need to update the image rect before blitting the image to the screen.  Sorry if you have done this already and this doesn't help.  Good luck with the game.  Also you need to work on the sprite images a little as they contrast with the background quite sharply.

Comment: Hello Marien. Thanks so much for your feedback. I tried including rocket.update() and iss.update() in the iss_hit code after the new iss and ship is placed but that didn't seem to help. If you see above I seem to have discovered a symptom of the problem, any advice or suggestions about which part of the code that I'm not posting that I should be is much appreciated.